# buffer vs bytearray vs str in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

`BinaryField`. Type of this field is `buffer` because when I put:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.BinaryField()

p = Person()
type(p.name)
```

I get:

```
 <type 'buffer'>
```

So, I have buffer. Buffer is set of bytes so it contains just some numbers.
I can do:

```
s = str(p.name) # It works (1) 
b = bytearray(p.name) # It works as well (2)
```

Now, I consider what is difference. What exactly does mean (1) and what does mean (2)?
Perhaps, I cannot grasp how Python ( CPython) represents strings. Please explain.

Comment: Please include your Python version.

Comment: I included in tags.